# How to prove $F$ is a contraction mapping?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, banach-algebras, fixed-point-theorems, nonlinear-system

Given a $n\times n$ matrix $\mathbf{D}$ in which each entry $\mathbf{D}_{ij} \in [0,1]$. Let $i$-th row vector of $\mathbf{D}$ denote by $\mathbf{D}_{i\ast}$. The mapping $F:[0,1]^n \mapsto [0,1]^n$, defined as
$$F(\mathbf{x})=[f_1(\mathbf{x}),f_2(\mathbf{x}),\cdots,f_n(\mathbf{x})]^T$$
where
$$f_i(\mathbf{x})=\frac{1}{1+\mathbf{D}_{i\ast}\cdot \mathbf{x}}$$

Now, how can I prove $F$ is a contraction mapping? 
Please help me!

Comment: what is the norm?

Comment: @Ian: For convergence (Banach Fixed Point Theorem) is not different but for contraction is important!

Comment: Please tell us what have you tried so far.

Comment: @Mohammad Khosravi: Can 1-norm guarantee contraction?

Comment: Yes! Since in finite dimension converging in any norm is enough!

Comment: @Sergio Parreiras: It is easy to prove that each component of $F$ is contractive. However, for multidimension, I have no idea.

Comment: Can you compute the Jacobian and then compute its norm?

Comment: Also it does not make sense to say a component of F is a contraction because a component of F is in $\mathbb{R}$ and $x$ is in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @Sergio Parreiras: Now, I can prove that the spectral radius of the Jacobian of $F$ at $\mathbf{x}^\ast$ is less than 1. ($\mathbf{x}^\ast$ is an arbitrary fixed point of $F$). This merely implies that $F$ locally converges to $\mathbf{x}^\ast$. However, I  want to show $F$ globally converge. Would you like to give me some tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

Let's use the max norm: $|| x||=\max |x_i|$.

The $(i,j)$ entry of the Jacobian: $Jf(x)_{ij} =-\dfrac{d_{ij}}{(1+D_{i*}x)^2}$.

Now  $\forall y$ such that $||y||=1$, we have $|| Jf(x) \cdot y ||\le \max_{i,j} d_{ij}<1$. Why? The are gaps here for you to fill. You need to use the fact $x\in [0,1]^n$.

So the norm of the Jacobian $||Jf(x)||:=\sup\limits_{y\,:\,||y||=1} || Jf(x) \cdot y ||<1$.

Remark:
 $x$ is an arbitrary point in the domain (not necessarily a fixed point).

Hint: To finish the proof, apply the mean value theorem...

Comment: @Pu.Fuan: Do you agree that $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}f_i(x)=\dfrac{-d_{ij}}{(1+D_{i*}\mathbf{x})^2}$?

Comment: I am very grateful for your hint. However, when $\mathbf{x}=0$ or $\mathbf{x}=\frac{1}{n+1}$ (the minimal value), then the Jacobian may greater than 1. The definition of contraction mapping is that on a metric space $<M,d>$, a function $f: M \mapsto M$ such that $$d(f(x),f(y))<kd(x,y), \forall x,y \in M$$ for some $0\leq k<1$. But though a program (randomly producting $x$ and $y$), I have verified that $F$ does not satisfy this property.

Comment: Yes, the Jacobian is right. Let the unique solution be ${v}^\ast \in [0,1]^n$, and ${F}'({v})$ be the Jacobian matrix of ${F}$ at ${v}$. Our main task is to prove the spectral radius of ${F}'({v}^\ast)$ less than $1$, i.e., $\rho\big({F}'({v}^\ast)\big) <1$.

Comment: First, we can obtain the Jacobian matrix
$$
  {F}'({v}^\ast) = [\frac{\partial\, f_i({v}^\ast)}{\partial\, v^\ast_j}]={J}({v}^\ast)\cdot\mathbf{D}
$$
where ${J}({v}^\ast)$ is a diagonal matrix with diagonal elements, for $i = 1,2,\cdots,n$,
$$[{J}({v}^\ast)]_{ii} = -1/(1+\mathbf{D}_{i\ast}\cdot{v}^\ast)^2 = -(v^\ast_i)^2$$

Comment: Second, for any $i \in \{1,2,\cdots,n\}$, $\mathbf{D}_{i\ast}\cdot{v}^\ast = \frac{1}{v^\ast_i} - 1$.
Then,
$$|{F}'({v}^\ast)|\cdot{v}^\ast = |{J}({v}^\ast)|\cdot\mathbf{D}\cdot{v}^\ast = |{J}({v}^\ast)|\cdot [\frac{1}{v^\ast_1}-1, \cdots, \frac{1}{v^\ast_n}-1]^T \\
   = {v}^\ast - \diag({v}^\ast)\cdot{v}^\ast < {v}^\ast $$
Repeatedly pre-multiplying $|{F}'({v}^\ast)|$ on both sides of this inequality, it follows that
$$
  |{F}'({v}^\ast)|^k\cdot{v}^\ast < |{F}'({v}^\ast)|^{k-1}\cdot{v}^\ast < \cdots < |{F}'({v}^\ast)|\cdot{v}^\ast < {v}^\ast
$$

Comment: What is $v^*_i$ ?

Comment: Anyway I stand by my hint/solution. Using $d(x,y)=\max |x_i-y_i|$ this mapping is a contraction with $k< \max d_{ij}$.

Comment: $v^\ast_i$ is the i-th component of $\mathbf{v}^\ast$

Comment: $-\dfrac{d_{ij}}{(1+D_{i*}v^*)^2} \mathbf{\neq} -(v^*_i)^2$

Comment: Yes, $-\dfrac{d_{ij}}{(1+D_{i*}v^*)^2} \mathbf{\neq} -(v^*_i)^2$. My Jacobian matrix is $F'(v^\ast)$. \\ $J(v\ast)=\frac{-1}{(1+\mathbf{D}_{i\ast}\cdot v^\ast)^2} = -(v^\ast_i)^2$, since $v^\ast$ is a fixed point of $F$.

Comment: Because $|{F}'({v}^\ast)|$ is non-negative and ${v}^\ast$ is positive, we must have
$$  \lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} |{F}'({v}^\ast)|^k\cdot{v}^\ast=\mathbf{0}
$$
Due to ${v}^\ast > \mathbf{0}$, therefore, there must be $\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow\infty} |{F}'({v}^\ast)|^k = \mathbf{0}$, which implies that $\rho\big(|{F}'({v}^\ast)|\big) < 1$